# Laravel returns a Collection with duplicates of the first model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, data-retrieval

I'm developing a Laravel `5.7` (API) application with a PostgreSQL database behind it. The relevant Models are: `User` (customers and employees), `Car`, and `Request`.

An *employee* `User` creates a `Request` for a `Car`, that belongs to a *customer* `User`.

The relationships are:

- `Car` <sub>(as *customer*)</sub> `:` `User` `=` `n:m`
- `Car` `:` `Request` `=` `1:n`
- `User` `:` `Request` <sub>(as *employee*)</sub> `=` `1:n`

[image]

<sub>(The data design is suboptimal, to put it mildly, but anyway, it's the given reality for now.)</sub>

Now to the actual issue. I want to display all `Request`s of a *customer* `User`:

```
Request::query()
    ->join('user_car', 'user_car.car_id', '=', 'request.car_id')
    ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'user_car.user_id')
    ->where('user.id', '=', $customer->id)
    ->select()
    ->get();
```

The *customer* with the given `$customer->id` has `n` `Request`s. And the length of the result `Collection` of the call above is correct. But all these `n` entries are duplicates of the first one. Means: I'm getting a list with `n` instances of `Request#1`.

**Why does the first call return a list of references to the same `Model` object?** Is it a (known) bug?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

**Relationships:**

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
{
    // ...
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car', 'user_car')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function requests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Request::class, 'user_id');
    }
}

class Car extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_car')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function requests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Request::class);
    }
}

class Request extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**The query is correct.**

I logged the database requests, got the generated statement

```
SELECT *
FROM "request"
INNER JOIN "user_car" ON "user_car"."car_id" = "request"."car_id"
INNER JOIN "user" ON "user"."id" = "user_car"."user_id"
WHERE "user"."id" = 1;
```

..., and executed it manually. The result table contains as expected `n` *different* entries.

**NOT just references**

The result `Collection`'s entries instances references to the different objects:

```
$test1 = $resultCollection->first();
$test2 = $resultCollection->last();
$test3 = spl_object_hash($test1);
$test4 = spl_object_hash($test2);
```

Xdebug output:

```
$test3 = "0000000077505ccd000000007964e0a8" <-- ccd0
$test4 = "0000000077505c33000000007964e0a8" <-- c330
```

**Workaround**

I found a workaround. This call

```
Request::whereIn('car_id', $customer->cars()->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
```

... retrieves the correct/expected set of model.

Comment: In your query, why aren't you just referencing the relationships? Can you show the relationships that you have in your User, Car and Request models? Also, you do not need to have the ->select() line in your query, just the get().

Comment: @eResourcesInc Thanks for your comment. `1`. "referencing the relationships" -- what do you mean? `$customer->cars->` ... and then? `2` "show the relationships" just updated the question (see the _ADDITIONAL INFORMATION_). `3`. "->select() line" -- correct, thanks!

Comment: In your workaround, why aren't you just setting $requests = $customer->cars()->requests()? And if that gives you the correct result, why would you write it out as a full query rather than just utilizing the simplicity of these relationship queries?

Comment: @eResourcesInc **1.** "$customer->cars()->requests()" -- This doesn't work. `Customer#cars()` returns a `BelongsToMany` object. So I get an exception "Call to undefined method ... BelongsToMany::requests()". Also `$customer->cars->requests()` would not work, since `$customer->cars` is a `Collection`, that doesn't know a `request()` method. **2.** "why ... full query" -- Yes, I've found a working solution. But I'm wondering, why the alternative way via the `Builder` is not working. Either I understand it wrong (then I want to know, what is my mistake), or it's a bug (then I want to report it).

Comment: Of course it would return a relation but I didn’t write out the whole query with ->get() because that would be up to you. The call for cars returns a collection of models which you then can utilize their relationships. So with a requests relationship on the car model, you absolutely should be able to follow the relationship path two levels and get what you require. I guess I don’t follow the point of the post and see you’re trying to see if it’s a bug but it’s probably some coding error as this is basic functionality and if it were buggy then almost no laravel application would work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your object hashes are not actually identical, and you're likely dealing with two separate instances.

What you're likely experiencing is an issue with **ambiguous column names**. When you `JOIN` together multiple tables, any matching/duplicate column names will contain the value of the last matching column. Your SQL GUI/client usually separates these. Unfortunately Laravel doesn't have a prefixing mechanism, and just uses an associative array.

Assuming all of your tables have a primary key column of `id`, every `Request` object in your result set will likely have the same ID - the User's ID you pass in the `WHERE` condition.

You can fix this in your existing query by explicitly selecting the columns you need to prevent ambiguity. Use `->select(['request.*'])` to limit the returned info to the `Request` object data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! **1** "object hashes are not actually identical" -- Yes, you are right. I've updated the question accordingly. **2** Thank you for the explanation! I would never think, that Eloquent doesn't prefix columns... In my opinion it's a very basic functionality for an ORM. And above all: If I execute a query on a concrete `Model` class, I presume to get only its objects -- without to need to specify this explicitly. Anyway, thank you for the explanation and the fix!